# HttpServletRequest cannot be resolved while i am trying to do my first program in Struts

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I just started writing a basic program for structs, i did installed tomcat and set the CATALINA_HOME to - C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.41

and set the path variable to - %CATALINA_HOME%\bin;

i have all the jar file of structs in my build path.

But when i try to write Action class with execute method and HttpServletResponce, HttpServletRequest as its parameters i am getting an error saying HttpServletRequest cannot be resolved to a type.

I did added the project to server by right click on server and going with add or remove option.

Do i need to do anything else to over come this error..

Please Advice, any guidance/Help is really appreciated.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Did you import `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`?

Comment: when i try to import it is say that it cannot be resolved

Comment: @Reimeus - Do i need to externally add the servlet jar's to my build path

Comment: @tom See [Tutorial Struts 1.x](http://blog.paulvargas.org/tutorial-struts-1-x-basico/)

Comment: You're missing the jar from the classpath. How are you building the project, maven, ant?

Comment: just a normal  project i am not using maven or ant

Comment: @PaulVargas  - i did went throw the tutorial , its the same way i wrote my program but i have problem importing the servlet request and responce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` is contained within the file `servlet-api.jar` which is located in `apache-tomcat\lib` which can be copied to the classpath

Aside: Build managers are a much cleaner way of managing such dependencies, for example

- [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/)
- [Ant (using Ivy)](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/)
- [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/)

Comment: class path under SystemVariable is like beow CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;JAVA_HOME\bin;CATALINA_HOME\lib; where CATALINA_HOME =  C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.41  but still i am geting the same error

Comment: That classpath will not suffice for compilation. You need to include the JAR file itself i.e. `%CATALINA_HOME%\lib\servlet-api.jar` :)

Comment: it worked that way, instead in class path can i add the jar in buildpath?

Comment: Yes you will need to do this. To clarify JAR files not directories need to specified when including 3rd party libraries. Again I'd recommend using a build manager to manage this